# How to install Ruby gem automatically, if required?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Given a Ruby program that uses a particular gem (e.g. [`term-ansicolor`](http://flori.github.com/term-ansicolor/)), how could I install the gem automatically, if required?

In other words, the program does:

```
require 'term/ansicolor'
```

and, in case the gem wasn't install previously, I would like to install it and continue the program rather than getting an error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- term/ansicolor
from (irb):1:in `require'
from (irb):1
from :0
```

What would be the most appropriate method to achieve that?

Comment: Installing software automatically, unless that's the program's sole purpose, isn't a good idea. 1) Installing software isn't an easy thing. 2) Some people might regard software that automatically installs other software without the user asking to do so as malware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a tool is not available. Read a detailed discussion about it here http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2728297

Answer (score 4):

I've been using this pattern:

```
require 'rubygems'
begin
  gem 'minitest'
rescue Gem::LoadError
  Gem.install('minitest')
  gem 'minitest'
end
require 'minitest'
```

Answer (score 3):

You should consider to use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/). It's the de-facto standard way to manage dependencies in Ruby software.

Comment: More precisely, Bundler's `--standalone` mode as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20215858/1127485) should do it, because obviously you don't want to install Bundler itself manually either.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could build your package into a gem and put the required gem as a dependency in the gemspec.  It would then get installed automatically when you install the gem.